# Dependency injection with abstract class in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, abstract-class

I don't know how to use a dependency injection in an abstract class. Let me show you my problem in a simple example:

```
public abstract class Animal {

    public abstract void Move();

    public void Sleep() 
    {
        restService.StartSleeping(1000);    //how to get this service here?
    }
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
    public readonly IMotionService _motionService;    

    public Cat(IMotionService motionService)
    {
       _motionService = motionService;
    }

    public override void Move()
    {
        _motionService.Run();
    }
}

public class Bird : Animal
{
    public readonly IMotionService _motionService;    

    public Bird(IMotionService motionService)
    {
       _motionService = motionService;
    }

    public override void Move()
    {
        _motionService.Fly();
    }
}
```

Every animal move in different way so the `Move()` function is implemented separately in every derived class. As you probably noticed the whole implementation comes from the `motionService`.
On the other hand all animals sleep in same way, so I want put the `Sleep()` implementation in a base abstract class to avoid a duplication code, but I can't use my `restService` with a `Sleep` implementation because I don't have idea how to inject a service class into an abstract class.

I thought about `IServiceProvider` but it should be injected too.

Comment: You inject `restService` into both the `Cat` and `Bird` ctors, and pass it down into the `Animal` ctor

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You pass it down like this:

```
public abstract class Animal 
{
    private readonly IRestService restService;

    public Animal( IRestService restService )
    {
        this.restService = restService;
    }

    public abstract void Move();

    public void Sleep() 
    {
        restService.StartSleeping(1000);
    }
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
    // vv Should be private!
    public readonly IMotionService _motionService;    

    public Cat(IMotionService motionService, 
               IRestService restService)
            : base(restService) // pass on to base class ctor
    {
       _motionService = motionService;
    }

    public override void Move()
    {
        _motionService.Run();
    }
}

// Same in `Bird` class
```

For reference: [Using Constructors (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-constructors)

Comment: this is gd, but i think you should also include how to register this for DI

Comment: @Seabizkit If OP managed to register and inject `IMotionService`, he should be able to register and inject `IRestService` accordingly, don't you think?

Comment: if IMotionService is different for each type of animal......... ...... then well fail

Comment: @Seabizkit No, it won't. It's the same service, just Bird and Cat use different methods from it. Have a look into the question code example. If they _were_ different implementations, then this would be a whole different question. This was about how to inject the restService into the base class.

Comment: maybe i missed something "Every animal move in different way so the Move() function is implemented separately in every derived class" i was under the impression that IMotionService has different implementations for each animal.

Comment: @Seabizkit It's the same service just Cats `Run()` and Birds `Fly()` :D